# How to run bash file with one word

Tags: linux, bash, shell

## Issue

I want to run a bash file more easily, I've seen some applications where you only need to type word to execute the script.

Instead of typing `~/folder/file.sh` in the terminal,
I only have to type `a_word` to run the file.

Is this possible with bash?

And also, this is on RPiOS's terminal, not sure if it differs.

Comment: use an alias. googe bash alias

Comment: @RedCricket, ...that's awful advice. See http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/alias -- notice how for years the #bash IRC channel gave as advice when anyone asked about aliases "use a function instead".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your file to a location named in PATH. `/usr/local/bin/a_word` (no `.sh`) is a great example of such a location. Make sure it has executable permissions and starts with a shebang (like `#!/usr/bin/env bash`).

When you want to install something just for your own account, it's common practice to create a `~/bin` directory and add it to your PATH (as by adding something like `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` in `~/.bash_profile`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a so called `alias`.

Edit the file `$HOME/.bashrc` and add `alias a_word = '$HOME/folder/file.sh'`, then logout and logon again.

Comment: thanks so much! I will make this the answer when it lets me.

Comment: Aliases are horrible and should never be used by anyone. They don't work in lots of contexts -- you can't use `find -exec some-alias` or run `:! some-alias` in vim; and they're turned off entirely in scripts.

Comment: When one doesn't want to use a script, it's still better to use a function than an alias. `a_word() { "$HOME/folder/file.sh" "$@"; }` -- functions can be exported to the environment, they work in scripts, they allow branching logic and let arguments be evaluated in non-final positions. The only time an alias is better than a function -- and it's a very rare case -- is if you want to expand to something that uses shell syntax in a way that's illegal without extra content the user is expected to type after the alias itself.